# Matter and antimatter collision

Tags: charge, antimatter, coulombs-law

When matter and antimatter collides annihilation takes place? Why does this happen?

Comment: If you take it as a simple question, there exists a simple answer: antimatter is a particle with all the opposite  conserved quantum numbers of the particle. When particle antiparticle meet all the conserved quantum numbers become zero and there is just energy from the interaction which can turn into any other combination of particles that adds up to zero conserved quantum numbers.